# Python opencv imwrite doesn't save images into destination

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to resize all images in my samples folder and then save all the images back in the test folder. The code below resize the images but it doesn't save them into the destination folder "test". I fail to understand what is the problem and I have referred to all documentation and nothing can help me understand what goes wrong here.

```
import cv2
import glob
import os
from tqdm import tqdm


imgs = glob.glob('samples/*.jpg')

print('Images files:', imgs)

width = 100
height = 100

folder = 'test'
if not os.path.exists(folder):
    os.makedirs(folder)

#Resizing & Saving
for img in tqdm(imgs):
    pic = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    pic = cv2.resize(pic, (width, height))
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(folder,img), pic)
    print(img)
```

The script can read the images and resize them successfully, the only part is imwrite doesn't function as expected.

Comment: `print os.path.join(folder,img)` -- does that give you a path you expect? Your script only creates the "test" directory, but you're quite likely trying to save things like "test/samples/foo.jpg"...

Comment: Images are read from samples folder but when I want to save it should be in test folder. So my path should be "test/foo.jpg".

Comment: Yes, I read the question. Notice that rather than asking you to explain again what you **think** it does, I've suggested some trivial debugging (about a minute's worth of effort) to verify that the path you're telling `imwrite` to save the image to **is actually the path you want**.

Answer (score 0):

May be the special character. Try to change the name of the image.

I don't have reputation to add this idea as comment. I'm Sorry.

Comment: By special character, are you referring to the `*` in `samples/*.jpg`?

Comment: Yes, @Andrew Myers!

Comment: The thing is, that's a glob, not an ordinary file path. The `*` is a wildcard that selects all files that end with `.jpg`. You can see some examples at https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html